# passing php object through $_POST securely

Tags: php, json, forms, post, serialization

I have an instantiated PHP object of class Student that I want to pass through a form via $_POST that is triggered by the user clicking on an li element. The javascript code submits the form. I want to retrieve the object via accessing $_POST and then assign the parameters of the object to php variables which will then be echoed to an input field. Is this secure if I use HTTPS? and how do I encode and then decode the PHP object so it can be passed through the form and then retrieved and reconstructed as an object of class Student? I am really not sure the best way to approach this as I have seen JSON used, serialise and base 64. NO current questions I checked seemed to have the full solution.

```
@$selected_student = $_POST['student_identifier'];

// instantiates the teacher object
$teacher = new Teacher();
$teacher->teacherId = $_SESSION['id'];

// getStudents method creates and returns an array of objects of class Student
$students = $teacher->getStudents($teacher->teacherId);

<form id="select_student" method='POST' action="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"> 
<?php
// iterates the student array displaying the name of each index in the array and setting the value as the student object  that I want passed via the form submission        
foreach($students as $studentObject) {
    ?>
    <li>
        <b><?php echo $studentObject->studentName; ?></b>
        <input type="hidden" id="student_identifier" name="student_identifier" value='<?php echo  serialize($studentObject); ?>'>
    </li>
    <?php
} 
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Its not safe, your not using a csrf token and your using `action="<?php echo ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>"` which opens XSS to your form.

Comment: I am using crsf tokens generated on each form submission - sorry this was just a snippet of the code

Comment: Ok, its hard to tell from your code, none of the actual `student_identifier` or `$studentObject` is used or defined anywhere. Im not sure why you would want to put an object in the data when a simple id would suffice (then lookup the object), also a big base64 string encourages further investigations by the curious. serialize does noting to protect the data.

Comment: Plus with ids `ints` you can encode them with base62 to obfuscate ids, or use libs like hashid

Answer (score 1):

It's not safe at all to use PHP `unserialize` on untrusted data (and anything that comes from HTTP request cannot be trusted regardless of using tokens or not).

The best approach is to pass only minumum data required to identify an object (such as student id) and then load it from the database by id. And (important!) don't forget to also verify the student's teacher.

If you absolutely cannot load the object from the database for whatever reason, you can employ some cryptography and encrypt and sign the value with a secret key stored only on the server, for example, in session. Then when you get the value from the request, verify the signature, decrypt and unserialize the value.